# SqlServerStorage in filehelpers 3.0.39

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm using Filehelpers 2.0 and SetProgressHandler to show the progress. Now I want to change to Filehelpers 3.0.39 and I can't use the SetProgressHandler because is not longer. How can I show the progress ???
The code I have in version 2.0 is :

```
SqlServerStorage storage = new SqlServerStorage(typeof(ExportarNuevasEmpresas));
....
storage.SetProgressHandler(new ProgressChangeHandler(ProgressChangeEx));

private void ProgressChangeEx(ProgressEventArgs e)     
{
    xpProgressBar1.Position = e.ProgressCurrent;
    xpProgressBar1.Text = "Registro " + e.ProgressCurrent.ToString();
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Maria

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SqlServerStorage storage = new SqlServerStorage(typeof(ExportarNuevasEmpresas));
//....
storage.Progress += storage_Progress;

private void storage_Progress(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
    xpProgressBar1.Position = e.Percent;
    xpProgressBar1.Text = "Registro " + e.Percent.ToString();
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  However, using this code, I have a problem with it in that e.Percent and e.TotalRecords return -1.  any suggestions?